# Does RegisterStartupScript increase page size

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using this code in a page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="timer" Interval="4000" runat="server" OnTick="timer_Tick" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAlarm" runat="server" CssClass="pnlAlarm" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <div id="Alarm">
                <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="Updating" CssClass="AlarmLogo"></asp:Label>
                    ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in code behind I use this simple code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["nima"] = 1;
    }
}
protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = int.Parse(Session["nima"].ToString());
    if (i==3)
    {
        lblContent.Text = i.ToString();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "AlarmMessage", "$('#pnlAlarm').slideToggle();", true);
        Session["nima"] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i = i + 1;
        Session["nima"] = i;
    }
}
```

I want to know every time that I use `RegisterStartupScript` , `$('#pnlAlarm').slideToggle();` add to my page and increase my page size?

thanlks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, that method will:

> register a startup script block that is included every time that an asynchronous postback occurs.

So yes, it will be included, and therefore increase your page size.

[msdn ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx)

Comment: please consider this scenario. I register a code block in my page and it's size increase 2 KB.now if I register it again does page size increase 4KB? and so on...